# Indexing method that gets parameters in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a store application with a Product scaffold and I want to enable categories and pages that show each category of products.

My product model has a "category" attribute and I use the link_to helper to create links to each category.

In my products controller I added a method called index_by_category(cat):

```
def index_by_category(cat)    
  @products_by_category = Product.where(category: cat)
end
```

I'm trying to iterate @products_by_category in a view I created with the corresponding name (product/index_by_category.html.erb) just like the regular index method do. For some reason it render me the regular index method of products which shows ALL of them, even though the URL is:

> http://localhost:3000/products?index_by_category=Food

This is what I did in my route.rb file:

```
get 'products/index_by_category'
```

I'm newbie to Rails development so if I did something which is wrong from the roots and the rails approach to the problem should be entirely different I also be happy to know for the sake of learning.

Comment: Add `get 'products/index_by_category'` before this line `resources :products` in your routes.rb file and then to check that route really exists, open a console and navigate to your project folder and run `bundle exec rake routes | grep index_by_category `

Comment: I recommendet to change the position of your route definition because Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified

Comment: @cristian it didn't solved the issue when I changed where I routed the function. However the second solution in the answer below did the work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing things a bit wrong. Try to write your controller like this:

```
def index_by_category   
  @products_by_category = Product.where(category: params[:category])
end
```

And update your route

```
get 'products/category/:category', to: 'products#index_by_category
```

Then visit

http://localhost:3000/products/category/Food

**UPDATE**

if you really want to use index method for both cases you could do that by modifying it to something like this

```
def index
  if params[:category]
    @products = Product.where(category: params[:category])
  else
    @products = Product.all
  end
end
```

and then just visit

http://localhost:3000/products?category=Food

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In this case, what the link_to path should look like? I still can't get it to work and rake routes gives me no path example.

Comment: In second case you need to pass extra params to the normal products index path, I believe it would be something like this: "products_path(category:'Food')"

Comment: Thank you very much. I learned a lot from your answer as a beginner. Thanks! I find the second solution you gave me very neat and simple :)